# oracle plsql stored procedure error handling ora-6502

Tags: plsql

```
create procedure about_emp(p_empno in number,p_ename out varchar2)
is
begin
select ename into p_ename from emp
where empno=p_empno;
exception
when no_data_found then
dbms_output.put_line('your id not available');
when value_error then
dbms_output.put_line('enter exact data');
end;
```

## execution

variable x varchar2(10);
exec about_emp(4520,:x);

### X

michel

exec about_emp(1111,:x);
you id not available

exec abot_emp('a',:x);
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1

but normally in store procedure are display like
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.about_emp", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1

please find the error and give me the solution

Comment: Please be gentle while asking questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, either you have declared X variable too small to hold the value of empno.ename, so make it larger.  If you also want to see the output from dbms_output in sqlplus, you need to enable:  "`set serveroutput on"`

Answer (score 0):

Procedure `about_emp` expects `number` data type as first formal parameter and `varchar` as second formal parameter.

```
create procedure about_emp(p_empno in number,p_ename out varchar2)
```

But while executing you are supplying `varchar` data type for the first formal parameter (where number is expected)

```
 exec abot_emp('a',:x);
```

Oracle can't do implicit conversion of `a` to a `number`, so that is why you are getting error `ERROR at line 1: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 1`
You should call this procedure supplying first actual parameter as number and second parameter as `varchar` (or compatible (or convertable) data types )

As per `exec about_emp(1111,:x); you id not available` 
This is just output from trapped exception

```
exception
when no_data_found then
dbms_output.put_line('your id not available');
```

It mean's that `SELECT` returned empty result set, there is no such data in the table.

**UPDATE** OP asked how to handle errors in PL/SQL

**1st option** - You need to associate error with the definition

```
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(invalid_implicit_conversion, -6789);
```

and then trap error in `EXCEPTION` section.

```
 EXCEPTION
      WHEN invalid_implicit_conversion 
      THEN ...
```

**2nd option** -

```
  EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS // this will trap any exception
          IF SQLCODE = -6789 THEN ...
```

Comment: but Mr. how to handle ora -6502 run time error  in my procedure like as no_data_found(ora-1403)  i handaled.

Comment: This s logical error, it should not be catched and handled, instead you shall correct your logic, invoke procedure in the correct way, with the correct arguments. I have updated my answer with information how to handle error in PL/SQL in regards to your last question.

Comment: but sir why this two errors showing showing different format

Comment: I did not understand your question, please elaborate.

Comment: when ora-1403 arises procedure gives error like ERROR at line 1: ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.about_emp", line 4 ORA-06512: at line 1 but when value -error arises  it shows differtly  ERROR at line 1: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 1.

Comment: procedure raise with scott.procedurename error but ora-6502 not showing any user.procedure

Comment: i cant understand why 6502 not arises in the procedure

Comment: `create procedure about_emp(p_empno in number,p_ename out varchar2)` what is the datatype of the first parameter?

Comment: first parameter is number

Comment: What about first parameter here `exec about_emp('a',:x); `?

Comment: it's character type

Comment: Error occurred on the procedure invocation, when Oracle DB tries to convert character to number.

Comment: ok sir than we have to specify the proper datatype at the call of the procedure

Comment: so if any user entered character datatype wrongly than

Comment: That is what front-end and back-end validation for.

Comment: hello Mr. can i put in my resume separably utl_file,sql*loader,bulk binding